# How to check if a tables exists using PDO with Idiorm

Tags: php, idiorm

```
/**
 * Check if a table exists in the current database.
 *
 * @param PDO $pdo PDO instance connected to a database.
 * @param string $table Table to search for.
 * @return bool TRUE if table exists, FALSE if no table found.
 */
function tableExists($pdo, $table) {

    // Try a select statement against the table
    // Run it in try/catch in case PDO is in ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
    try {
        $result = $pdo->query("SELECT 1 FROM $table LIMIT 1");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // We got an exception == table not found
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Result is either boolean FALSE (no table found) or PDOStatement Object (table found)
    return $result !== FALSE;
}
```

1. How to configure this function with Idiorm PDO?
2. Is it okey to use -

   ```
   try {
       $page = ORM::for_table($table)->where('slug', $slug )->find_one();  
   } (catch $e) {
       // 404 with an error that table does not exists.
   }
   ```

instead of the "tableExists" function?

Comment: Is it resolve your problem? Use it. Is there an Idiorm function for this purpose? No? Use Idiorm code without problem. The only thing what you have be concerned, if you're using a ORM, why the heck would you use the native way? Use only one way, don't mix the things there.

Comment: @GabrielHeming, yo, idiorm doesn't provide functionallity for this. I just catch an error before it throws exception, but is it okey? I mean is it the right way?

Comment: Sure, it does. What I mean (with all my questions) is to instigate your own question. If some library doesn't provide something, there's no problem of use the library of your purpose. The only "but" is, don't mix the things, PDO is PDO and Idiorm is Idiorm, even Idiorm uses PDO. At last, use only Idiorm or only PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly you want to check if a table exists in a MySQL database.

### Q. 1

It should be noted that the two queries are not identical. You've got:

```
$page = ORM::for_table($table)->where('slug', $slug )->find_one();
```

But your second query should be:

```
$page = ORM::for_table($table)->select_expr(1)->find_one();
```

See the [result columns documentation](https://idiorm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querying.html#result-columns) for information.

### Q. 2

Yes, Idiorm uses PDO underneath so you'll get the same PDO exception - this is something you really could just try and see how it works with:

```
try {
    $page = ORM::for_table($table)->where('slug', $slug )->find_one();  
} (catch $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```